# I need to create a php form to update a database table using the IDs I got from a previous query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a intranet site where a user logs in, and a list of projects that are his responsability are displayed(these are pulled from the database) - index.php

THe user then clicks on one of the projects, which will in turn present the project requirements.Again this is queried from the database. this last result is actually  composed of three queries: the first uses the project name to get the project id, the second gets uses the project id to get the requirements id , and the third uses the requirements id to get the requirement itself, a string, which is displayed.-project.php

The requirements are displayed in a table which as an input form, to update the completion status of that requirement. I have a table called project eval that has the project ID, Requirmentd ID and Requirement fullfilment.

What I need is allow the user to input the fullfilment value and save it directly to the database, in the correspondent requirement row. My ideia is to use requirement id associated with he requirement itself to update the fullfilment values.

The problem is I searched and I cant find how to...

Project php-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<?
   session_start();
   //Read your session (if it is set)
   if (isset($_SESSION['userlogin']))
      echo $_SESSION['userlogin'];


?>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <title>Project Requirements</title>
    <body>

<div class="header"> </div>
<?php include ('Header.php') ?>

<div class="navbar"> </div>
<?php include ('NavBar.php') ?>

<div class="loggeduser">

<p align="center">  

<? 

    if ($username = $_SESSION['username']) {
    echo "Welcome $username";}
    else {
        echo "<a href=login.php>Please log in first</a>";
        exit;
    }   
?>

<form action=logoff.php name=logoff>
<p align=center>
    <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1"  VALUE = "Log out" style=font-weight:bolder; color:white; background-color:#990000;></form>
</p>
</div>

<div class="dbcontent"> 
<?
//db connection
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','', 'qef');



// Get ProjID based on $id
$Pid =$_GET['id'];                  



$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','', 'qef');

//Get ProjID
$query ="SELECT ProjID FROM project WHERE ProjName='$Pid'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
// Assgn ProjID to $ProjID
(list($ProjID) = mysqli_fetch_row($result)); 


//Get ReqID
$query ="Select ReqID FROM projreq WHERE ProjID='$ProjID'";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);


//Assign ReqID to $ReqID
$ReqIDa=array ();
While ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

    array_push ($ReqIDa, $row[0]);    

};

?>


<form action="rfullfilment.php" method="post">
<table border="0" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><th>Project Requirements</th></td><td><th>Completion Status</th></td><td><th>Save</th></td>
    </tr>
<?php
//Assign Req to $Req
foreach ($ReqIDa as $ReqID)
{
$query ="Select Req FROM requirement WHERE ReqID='$ReqID'"; 
$result= mysqli_query($link,$query);    
$Req= mysqli_fetch_row($result);

?>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $Req[0]; ?></td><td><input type="text" name="rfullfilment" value=""></td><td ><input type="Submit" value="Save" name="Submit"></td>
        <
    </tr>
<?php
}


?>


</table>    

</form>
</div>

<div class="footer"> </div>
<?php include ('Footer.php')?>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

Rfullfilment.php

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','', 'qef');

$Pid =$_GET['id'];  
$rfullfilment = $_POST['rfullfilment'];

//Get ProjID
$query ="SELECT ProjID FROM project WHERE ProjName='$Pid'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
// Assgn ProjID to $ProjID
(list($ProjID) = mysqli_fetch_row($result)); 


//Get ReqID
$query ="Select ReqID FROM projreq WHERE ProjID='$ProjID'";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);


//Assign ReqID to $ReqID
$ReqIDa=array ();
While ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

    array_push ($ReqIDa, $row[0]);    

};

foreach ($ReqIDa as $ReqID)
{
$query ="UPDATE projreq SET Rfullfilment='$rfullfilment' WHERE ReqID='$ReqID[0]'"; 
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query); 
//$Req=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
};

//Update Rfullfilment
if(mysql_query($query)){
echo "updated";}
else{
echo "fail";};

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to understand more clearly. Is it a scenario where like this. Get some details from 1st form -> proceed to next form -> proceed to next form -> use the details from all the previous forms and do something here

Comment: let me try to simplify then. On the requirements page I have an input field. I want to use that input and save to the db.in order to identify the correct row, i use an ID I got from a previous form. does it make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for $_GET['id'] in fulfillment.php, but you are not sending it with the form on project.php

You should either change the form action to

```
<form action="rfullfilment.php?id=<?php echo $Pid; ?>" method="post">
```

or add a hidden form field to transfer the data.

```
<input type=hidden name=id value=<?php echo $Pid; ?>>
```

and then change `$_GET['id'] to $_POST['id']` on your fulfillment.php code.

I am not sure this answers your question, the last bit is a little confusing for me.

Comment: I overlook that part, but that also helps with another issue i was having. if you look at project.php, , here:                        'code' //Assign ReqID to $ReqID
$ReqIDa=array ();
While ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

    array_push ($ReqIDa, $row[0]);    

};

?>'code'                                                                      I need to pass these data to the rfullfilment.php so that each input field will update the correct fullfilment row, as each of the requeriments has a associated reqid. I need to associate that id an requirment to the corresponding input field

Comment: OK, that helped. but i still need to retrieve an ReqID and associate it with the correct requirement, where the input box is. So when the use puts a value, the query will update the row with that req id

Comment: You have an input and submit for each ReqID. Next to each text input, put a hidden input with name='ReqID' value='<?php echo $ReqID[0]; ?>' so your update script knows exactly what ID you want to update.